# Local System.Data.SQLite database creation and CRUD in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, sqlite

I am planning to port an existing WindowsForms app into either Silverlight or WPF. The existing app uses System.Data.SQLite. It would be no problem to do the same in WPF, but I have searched for a couple of days now and the information is quite confusing:

So is the same possible in a Silverlight OOB?

Requirements:
1) Silverlight OOB
2) Cache: Dynamically create System.Data.SQLite database files (+queries) on the local disk in different folders (somewhere in the User Documents for example)
3) The cache has to be fast and might need up to 4GB, which rules out some of the standard Silverlight DBs.

I tried COM access, but cannot get it to work:

```
        private void CreateConnection()
    {
        Conn = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
        recordSet = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet");

        Conn.Open(@"Data Source=XXX;Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false");
    }
```

I cannot use System.Data.SQLite directly in Silverlight. But System.Data.SQLite is an ADO.NET service, so I would think that should work somehow?

My next thought was to create a WCF RIA access to the db, which would also give me the possibility to move the db access to a remote server in other environments. But what is the approach here when the service does not point to a certin db with known entities, but dbs are created in different folders? And does that work at all?

Some help appreciated...